# In any triangle, $a^2(B-C)+b^3\cos (C-A)+c^2\cos (A-B)=3abc$.

Tags: trigonometry

Let $A,B,C$ by the angles of a triangle, and let $a,b,c$ be the length of the corresponding opposite sides.

How can you prove that

$$a^3\cos(B-C) + b^3\cos(C-A) +c^3\cos(A-B) = 3abc?$$

I divided both sides by $abc$ and then tried to open the cosine function but nothing worked. I also took the cube of sine in the triple angle identity but that too just made the function more complicated and yielded no result.

Comment: What is your reason for thinking the equation is true?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Because if the equation would be true, after dividing both sides by $abc$ the and solving the LHS, the answer would have come out to be 3. I assume the the equation is true and if the answer doesn't come equal to 3, that would have been in contrast to our assumption.

Comment: See http://www.askiitians.com/forums/Trigonometry/in-a-triangle-abc-prove-that-a-3-cos-b-c-b-3-cos_123839.htm

Comment: My question was, why do you assume the equation is true? Though it hardly matters any more, now that you have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $2R=k$

$a=k\sin A, b=k\sin B,c=k\sin C$ (sine rule)

$$ a^3 \cos (B-C)= a^2\cdot a\cos (B-C)=$$
$$= a^2\cdot k\sin A\cos (B-C)= ka^2\sin (180-(B+C))\cos (B-C)=$$
$$= ka^2\sin (B+C)\cos (B-C)=\frac{ka^2}{2} (\sin 2B+\sin 2C) = $$
$$=\frac{ka^2}{2} (2\sin B\cos B+2\sin C\cos C) = ka^2(\sin B\cos B+\sin C\cos C) = $$
$$= a^2((k\sin B)\cos B+(k\sin C)\cos C)) =$$$$= a^2 (b\cos B+c\cos C)$$

The original expression now looks like this:
$$a^2(b\cos B+c\cos C)+b^2(c\cos C+a\cos A)+c^2(a\cos A+b\cos B) = $$
$$= a^2b\cos B + a^2c\cos C+b^2c\cos C+b^2a\cos A+c^2a\cos A+c^2b\cos B$$
$$= 
a^2b\cos B + 
b^2a\cos A +
b^2c\cos C +
c^2b\cos B +
a^2c\cos C +
c^2a\cos A
$$
$$=ab(a\cos B+b\cos A)+bc(b\cos C+c\cos B)+ca(a\cos C+c\cos A) =$$

[image: Triangle]
$$= abc+bca+cab = 3abc$$

Answer (score 1):

Using $\cos{(x-y)}=\frac{\sin{x}\cos{x}+\sin{y}\cos{y}}{\sin{(x+y)}}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\cos{(B-C)} 
&=\frac{\sin{B}\cos{B}+\sin{C}\cos{C}}{\sin{(B+C)}} \\
&=\frac{b\cos{B}+c\cos{C}}{a} \;\;\; \text{[By extended Law of Sines]} 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
& \therefore \; \sum_{cyc} {a^3\cos{(B-C)}} \\
&= \sum_{cyc} {a^2(b\cos{B}+c\cos{C}) } \\
&= a^2(b\cos{B}+c\cos{C})+b^2(c\cos{C}+a\cos{A})+c^2(a\cos{A}+b\cos{B})\\
&= ab(a\cos{B}+b\cos{A})+bc(b\cos{C}+c\cos{B})+ca(c\cos{A}+a\cos{C}) \\
&= abc+abc+abc \;\;\; \text{[Using Projection Formulas]} \\
&= 3abc
\end{align*}
$QED.$