# How to Prove $a^3 \cos (B-C) + b^3 \cos (C-A)+ c^3 \cos (A-B)=3abc$?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

### How to Prove $a^3 \cos (B-C) + b^3 \cos (C-A)+ c^3 \cos (A-B)=3abc$?

If $A,$ $B,$ and $C$ are the vertices of the Triangle ABC, and $a,$ $b$ and $c$ is the side opposite to the sides of the triangle.

You may use -

Projection Formula:

$$a=b \cos C + c \cos B$$

and Sine and Cosine Relation too.

---

My try

$$a^3 \cos (B - C)+ b^3 \cos (C-A) + c^3 \cos (A-B)=3abc$$
LHS =
$$ 3(b \cos C + c \cos B)(a \cos C + c \cos A)(a \cos B + b \cos A)$$
$$ 3[ ab \cos B \cos ^2 C + abc \cos A \cos B \cos C +a^2c \cos ^2 B \cos C +ac^2 \cos A \cos ^2B ]+[b^2 \cos A \cos^2 C + b^2c \cos^2 A \cos A+abc \cos A \cos B \cos C + ac^2 \cos A \cos^2 B] $$

Now I can't solve it further because there seems no way to reduce that further.

Thanks :)

Comment: https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Trigonometry/in-a-triangle-abc-prove-that-a-3-cos-b-c-b-3-cos_123839.htm

Comment: @labbhattacharjee How do others know about this Question? Who made them? source? if you know?

Comment: Your last line has several errors.  I suggest you redo the calculation again before trying to proceed further.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Oh, I see

Comment: sine, cosine rule  and $R=\frac{abc}{\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)(-a+b+c)}}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigonometry- Triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820624/trigonometry-triangles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be proved with sine-rule and cosine rule but it is really ugly.

$${\rm LHS} - {\rm RHS} =
\sum_{cyc} ( a^3\cos(B-C) - abc )
= \sum_{cyc}( a^3(\cos B\cos C + \sin B\sin C) - abc)$$
By sine rule,

$$a : b : c = \sin A : \sin B : \sin C
\quad\implies\quad \begin{cases}
a^3\sin B\sin C = abc\sin A^2\\
b^3\sin C\sin A = abc\sin B^2\\
c^3\sin A\sin B = abc\sin C^2
\end{cases}$$
This leads to

$$\begin{align}{\rm LHS} - {\rm RHS}
&= \sum_{cyc}( a^3 \cos B \cos C - abc\cos^2 A)\\
&= \sum_{cyc}\left[a^3\left(\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}\right)\left(\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\right) - abc\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right)^2\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{4abc}\sum_{cyc}a^2(\underbrace{a^4 - (b^2-c^2)^2 - (b^2+c^2-a^2)^2}_{I})
\end{align}
$$
Notice what's in the square bracket equals to
$$\require{cancel}I =\cancel{a^4} - (b^2-c^2)^2 - (b^2+c^2)^2 + 2a^2(b^2+c^2) - \cancel{a^4}
=2(a^2(b^2+c^2) - b^4-c^4)$$ 
We obtain

$$\begin{align}{\rm LHS} - {\rm RHS} 
&= \frac{1}{2abc}\sum_{cyc} a^4b^2 + \color{red}{a^4}\color{green}{c^2} - a^2 b^4 - \color{blue}{a^2}\color{magenta}{c^4}\\
&= \frac{1}{2abc}\sum_{cyc} a^4b^2 + \color{red}{b^4}\color{green}{a^2} - a^2 b^4 - \color{blue}{b^2}\color{magenta}{a^4}\\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

Comment: A beautiful equation hiding under an Ugly Proof!

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I agree the equation itself is beautiful, I suspect there is a geometric proof behind it.

Comment: I think that this is theoretical proof only because we are taught derivation and the formula only today, because next month we will be high school

Comment: But how you Broke that all cosine ratios to convert difference of angles to single angle?

Comment: Oh okay, But I think that answer can be presented in more simple manner, but heck yeah! Complicated ones look better

Comment: Does using $\sigma$ instead of long chains of expression while proving '0' always works?

Comment: $\sum_{cyc}$ refers to cyclic sum over $a,b,c$. Because the sum is cyclic, for any expression $f(a,b,c)$, you have $\sum_{cyc}f(a,b,c) = \sum_{cyc}f(b,c,a) = \sum_{cyc} f(c,a,b)$. That's why you can replace the colored terms in the expression by corresponding terms (and cancelled them in this case).

Comment: Can you try this question on Quora? - https://www.quora.com/unanswered/If-the-sides-of-the-Triangle-are-a-b-sqrt-a-2-ab-b-2-then-find-greatest-angle-find-the-measured-value-of-the-angle-not-which-one-is-greatest-See-Comment-for-more-details-about-the-Question

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I don't use quora.